# How can I make pentaho spoon auto-create a table?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am having few issues with pentaho spoon: I want to copy a table from one database to another.

When I click on "copy table" in the tool menu, it auto creates the transformation for that. But when I run it then I get these issues:

1. The truncate table is ticked that's why I get the error that my table does not exist.
2. I have to manually un-tick that. Even then I get an error because the table is not created. I have to click on the SQL and then execute the query. Is there any way to automatically do it?
3. Third problem is that pentaho created table is not detecting the date field, so it's putting the date type as `UNKNOWN`. I have to manually change that to `varchar`. Is there any way to fix that or default to `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 0):

The UNKNOWN data type is typically a driver issue. What database are you using and do you have the right driver?

There is no way to automate the creation of the table within PDI - it's deliberate that it does not do this.  You could however integrate PDI with a tool which does do this, something like dbDeploy is a good idea.

*UPDATE* There is now a way to automatically create tables, you can follow the blueprint here:

https://github.com/mattcasters/blueprints